# How to use OpenCV SortIdx() in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, opencv

I'm new in OpenCV and I using it in its version for Python. My problem is, I need to sort a matrix and I found the method sortIdx(), which seems solve my problem, but I don't know how to use. I have the following code:

```
matr=np.array([
            [6,8,5,12],
            [2,1,10,9],
            [3,4,11,7]
        ])
sorted_matr=cv2.sortIdx(matr,cv2.SORT_EVERY_COLUMN|cv2.SORT_ASCENDING)
print(sorted_matr)
```

It gives me the following result:

```
[[1 1 0 2]
 [2 2 1 1]
 [0 0 2 0]]
```

When I hope something like this (I'm not looking for M-1 element-wise it's only an example):

```
[[5 7 4 11]      [[6 4 7 0]
 [1 0 9 8]        [10 11 2 3]
 [2 3 10 6]]  or  [9 8 1 5]]
```

Anyway, I'm only interested in know how to use `sortIdx` in Python (I've only found documentation in C++ and the function receive in second parameter a new matrix...) to sort a matrix and how to use this new order.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

For basic matrix operations, NumPy can be a better choice than OpenCV.  OpenCV's [sortIdx](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#sortidx) can only sort *either* rows or columns independently, while [numpy.sort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) can flatten the matrix before sorting (`axis=None`):

```
sorted_matr = np.sort(matr, axis=None).reshape(matr.shape)
```

The result is

```
[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
 [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
 [ 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Alternatively, the following code gives the same result using indexes to sort: ([numpy.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) corresponds to OpenCV's sortIdx.)

```
sort_idxs = np.argsort(matr, axis=None)
sorted_matr = matr.flatten()[sort_idxs].reshape(matr.shape)
```

Note: the `sort_idxs` here are `[ 5,  4,  8,  9,  2,  0, 11,  1,  7,  6, 10,  3]`, which does not match what you have in your question since they are meant to be used for sorting, not for giving the rank for each element.